# How would I convert this Delphi Set code to C#?

Tags: c#, delphi, set

I've got the following Delphi code that defines a set and then a simple if statement that checks if a passed value of the set type falls within certain values.

```
TOverwriteMode = (omNone, omDateAndSize, omDateOrSize, omDate, omSize, omForce);

...

if OverwriteMode in [omDateAndSize, omDateOrSize, omDate, omSize] then
begin
end;
```

I've converted it to C# using an `enum`, but the code for checking the value now consists of an `if or` statement which seems a bit long winded to me.

```
public enum FileOverwriteMode
{
    None,
    DateAndSize,
    DateOrSize,
    Date,
    Size,
    Force,
}

...

if ((overwriteMode == FileOverwriteMode.DateAndSize) || 
    (overwriteMode == FileOverwriteMode.DateOrSize) || 
    (overwriteMode == FileOverwriteMode.Date) || 
    (overwriteMode == FileOverwriteMode.Size))
{
}
```

Is there a way to simplify it using some kind of C# set equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can do:

```
private static readonly HashSet<FileOverWriteMode> ValidOverwriteModes
    = new HashSet<FileOverWriteMode>
{
    FileOverwriteMode.DateAndSize, FileOverwriteMode.DateOrSize,
    FileOverwriteMode.Date, FileOverwriteMode.Size,
};

...

if (ValidOverwriteModes.Contains(overwriteMode))
{
    // ...
}
```

(Rename `ValidOverwriteModes` depending on what the real meaning is.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, that works nicely. I just needed to add HashSet<FileOverwriteMode> after the readonly to make it compile and it was good to go! (Apologies for the name typo!)

Comment: @Pauk: Doh - that was due to having `var` there before :) Will edit it into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
FileOverwriteMode overwriteMode = FileOverwriteMode.DateAndSize;
if (new HashSet<FileOverwriteMode> 
    { 
        FileOverwriteMode.DateAndSize, 
        FileOverwriteMode.DateOrSize, 
        FileOverwriteMode.Date, 
        FileOverwriteMode.Size 
    }.Contains(overwriteMode))
{
}
```

Comment: I thought it would be HashSet, but wasn't sure how to go about it. I like the inline creation, but John's answer just sneaks it for me since it will be checked upon a lot, so having it already created helps.