# How to convert a set of enumeration range from Delphi to C#?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi

I have these Delphi types:

```
type Color = (Red, Green,Blue);
type Colors = set of Color;
```

then Colors is used as a property type in other types

I am trying to convert this to C#. My attempt:

```
 public enum Color
    {
    Red, Green,Blue
    }

public class Colors
{
  public Color[] CColor;
}
```

I was wondering if there's a better equivalent way.

Comment: `CColor` is that a typo..?

Comment: No. It's an arbitrary property name. I chose it so it's not confused with the enum name.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/2310645/62576 help?